# ERROR:network_change_notifier_win.cc(226)] WSALookupServiceBegin failed with: 0

Tags: 20.04, wine, chromium

I am having the error while running a custom browser inside wine (wine-5.0) in Ubuntu 20.04 . The browser is a customized version of Chromium.

Googling displayed a few results, in which all ended up with similar results, and no solution.

I wanted to use wine, instead of using virtualbox and save a great amount of time & processing just to run a browser customized to run in windows.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Hello. This then would be an issue with your custom browser. Nothing Ubuntu related. Sorry.